# Django Rest Framework: Nested serializers returning a dictionary but list is desired

Tags: python, django, nested, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a basic Question Answer app. Here is my Questions model:

```
    class Questions(models.Model):
       created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       question = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default='')
       asked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='question_user', null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       upvote_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, related_name='advicesv1_upvote_question')
```

Now, I want to send the usernames/first_names of the people in 'asked_by' and 'upvote_by' instead of ids which is sent by default. To implement this I used a nested serializer like this:

```
    class QuesUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ('username',)

    class NewQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      question_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id', required=False)
      asked_by = QuesUserSerializer(read_only=True)
      upvote_by = QuesUserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

      class Meta:
       model = Questions
       fields = ('question_id', 'created', 'question', 'asked_by', 'upvote_by',)
```

due to this, my current response is like this:

```
    {
      "question_id": 182,
      "created": "2017-03-07T10:53:16.241533Z",
      "question": "hey what's up?",
      "asked_by": {
        "username": "testuser141"
      },
      "upvote_by": [
       {
         "username": "testuser"
       },
       {
         "username": "testuser1"
       }
  ]
},
```

But my desired response is:

```
    {
     "question_id": 182,
     "created": "2017-03-07T10:53:16.241533Z",
     "question": "hey what's up?",
     "asked_by": "testuser141",
     "upvote_by": ["testuser", "testuser1",....],
    },
```

What is the best way to achieve this using django restframework serializers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `to_representation` method of the nested serializer so that your `QuesUserSerializer` returns a string for each user, rather than an object.

```
class QuesUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.username
```

Answer (score 1):

try to override to representation method, like this:

```
class NewQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id', required=False)
    asked_by = QuesUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    upvote_by = QuesUserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields = ('question_id', 'created', 'question', 'asked_by', 'upvote_by',)
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = super(NewQuestionSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        data['asked_by']= obj.asked_by.username
        data['upvoted_by'] = obj.upvote_by.all().values_list('username', flat=True)
        return data
```

this only changue the representation of object, but not the logic of save o update...

Answer (score 0):

Although [natbot1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42986589/4797469) answer works, a more elegant solution is to use a [slugrelatedfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield)